# CMake - BUILD_SHARED_LIBS for single libraries

Tags: cmake

Is there a variable like BUILD_SHARED_LIBS but only for a single target (e.g. MyLib_BUILD_SHARED where MyLib is the library).

I know that I can manually determine if a library is static or dynamic using `STATIC` or `DYNAMIC` in the command `add_library`, but I want an option that can be set by a user instead of a hard coded solution.

Sincerely,
Lehks

Comment: `DYNAMIC` is not correct, it's `SHARED` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no builtin method in CMake that I'm aware of. Make it an option, that has the advantage of also documenting the intention to users.

```
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries (.dll/.so) instead of static ones (.lib/.a)" ON)
```

Then do the `add_library` command according to the option that was set.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer ignores the global `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` flag the user might have set.  We can factor in this flag and expose a user overridable option with `cmake_dependent_option`.

Here's an example, where a static library is build by default, unless `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is set to true.  User can also not set `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` but override just this libary to be built as shared.

```
include(CMakeDependentOption)
cmake_dependent_option(
  MYMATH_STATIC             # option variable
  "Build static library"    # description
  ON                        # default value if exposed; user can override
  "NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS"   # condition to expose option
  OFF                       # value if not exposed; user can't override
)

# set build type based on dependent option
if (MYMATH_STATIC)
  set(MYMATH_BUILD_TYPE STATIC)
else ()
  set(MYMATH_BUILD_TYPE SHARED)
endif ()

# use build type in library definition
add_library(mymath ${MYMATH_BUILD_TYPE}
  header.h
  source.cpp
)
```

If `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is defined *and* is *truthy*<sup>1</sup>, `MYMATH_STATIC` isn't exposed as an option at all; user can't override a non-existant option.

```bash
# builds libmymath.dll/.so/.dylib
cmake -B build -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1

# builds libmymath.dll/.so/.dylib ignoring MYMATH_STATIC
cmake -B build -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 -DMYMATH_STATIC=1
```

Otherwise, the option is available and the user can override it:

```bash
# builds libmymath.a since BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is left unset
cmake -B build -DMYMATH_STATIC=1

# builds libmymath.a since MYMATH_STATIC defaults to ON
cmake -B build

# builds libmymath.dll/.so/.dylib since BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is left unset
cmake -B build -DMYMATH_STATIC=0
```

<sup>1: `TRUE`, `1`, `ON`, `YES`, `Y` or a non-zero number</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I believe the accepted answer is not entirely accurate because the question was specifically about setting this option for a *single* target. By making `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` visible as an option, you control the `STATIC`/`SHARED` property of *all* library targets by default.

It is true that there is no built-in feature to do this for a single target. You would need to add that yourself. Something like the following:

```
option(MyLib_SHARED_LIBS "" ON)
if (MyLib_SHARED_LIBS)
   add_library(MyLib SHARED "")
else()
   add_library(MyLib STATIC "")
endif()
```

Comment: For ease the use in a super project I prefer to use `option(MyLib_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "" ${BUILD_SHARED_LIB})`

Comment: That's `${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS}`

Comment: @Mizux: Note that with that approach, if a user changes `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` via cmake-gui, the `MyLib_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` will remain at its old value. This may lead to unexpected results.